# Setup a layout for my contact list apk

Tags: android

I am trying to setup a new contact list for my apk but I can't figure out how to place a drawable in between the two rows.

Here is the code for my drawable:

```
<ImageView android:id="@id/divider" android:background="@drawable/divider" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Here is my layout for the contact list:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/conversations_row_height"  
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <com.whatsapp.LoadPhotoImageView android:id="@id/contactpicker_row_photo"
 android:layout_width="@dimen/imageview_size"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_size"
 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/imageview_padding"
 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/imageview_padding_right"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="6.0dip"
 android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/contactpicker_row_phone_type"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contactpicker_row_photo">
         <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView android:textSize="18.0sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff999999"
 android:ellipsize="end" android:gravity="left"
 android:id="@id/contactpicker_row_name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
 android:layout_marginRight="3.0dip"
 android:layout_marginBottom="1.0dip" android:singleLine="true"
 android:layout_weight="1.0" />
             <TextView android:textSize="12.0sp" android:textColor="#ff999999" android:gravity="right|center"
 android:layout_gravity="right|center"
 android:id="@id/contactpicker_row_phone_type"
 android:paddingTop="1.5dip" android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
         </LinearLayout>
         <TextView android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#ff999999" android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:gravity="left" android:id="@id/contactpicker_row_status"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="2.0dip"
 android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip" android:singleLine="true" />
     </LinearLayout>
     <View android:id="@id/contact_picker_divider_lower" android:background="@drawable/gradient"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0px"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
     <View android:id="@id/contact_picker_divider_upper" android:background="@drawable/gradient" android:paddingBottom="2.0dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1.0px"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

Could someone drive me to a solution please ?

Comment: have you got a drawable called "divider" in your project?